# load ng-include from content script element creation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I wish to load a template inside an ng-include from my content script.

here is what I have:

**file structure**

```
app/
--app/app.js
--app/form.html

js/
--js/background.js
--js/content.js
```

**content.js**

```
    var mydiv=document.createElement("div"); 
    //Next line is where I want to apply some angular functionality
    mydiv.innerHTML += "<div ng-app='app'></div>";

    mydiv.setAttribute('ng-include', "'app/form.html'");
    mydiv.id = "popup";
    mydiv.style.position = "fixed";
    mydiv.style.top = coords.y + "px";
    mydiv.style.left = coords.x + "px";
    mydiv.style.border = "4px solid #d00";
    mydiv.style.background = "#fcc";

    document.body.appendChild(mydiv); 
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'])
```

**form.html**

```
<div ng-controller="popupCtrl">
    test
</div>
```

if I try to use absolute path it seems that angular is popping errors, and if not it uses a combination of the tab current page url and my given path, which of course results in a 404 not found.

if I use `app/form.html` or `form.html`, It doesn't return error but instead load the current page into my div (as an iframe would do)

does someone has an idea, or an error I made to pin point? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like path issue, it should be `/app/form.html`

Comment: nop, as said this path results in a 404 error: angular.js:9814 GET http://stackoverflow.com/app/form.html 404 (Not Found) (tested on this page)